# How to host node.js service on UCP using Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins, docker-ucp

- I Have Multiple node service's. I want to deploy these service as a
  docker container in UCP.
- I am using Jenkins for CI CD.
- Using docker api (docker tag/push/) I am able to push the image into
  DTR.
- My Question is how can how to host the docker container on UCP on the basis of docker Image which I pushed into DTR.
- I was doing some POC on `Docker Build and Publish` Jenkin plugin but
  not able to figure out exact configuration.
  Also I wanted to know how can I run the `docker-compose.yml` on UCP to pull the image from DTR and hot it as a docker container using Jenkins

Any Help will be appriciable !!

Thanks in advance .